# ¿Cómo modelar el acertijo del lobo, la cabra y la col?

Tags: java, algoritmos

Pensando el en reto del [Año Nuevo algorítmico 2019](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3842/a%C3%B1o-nuevo-algor%C3%ADtmico-2019?cb=1) se me ocurrio la pregunta ¿De que manera puedo modelar el famoso acertijo del lobo, la cabra y la col?.

El acertijo dice así:
Hace mucho tiempo un granjero fue al mercado y compró un lobo, una cabra y una col. Para volver a su casa tenía que cruzar un río. El granjero dispone de una barca para cruzar a la otra orilla, pero en la barca solo caben él y una de sus compras.

Si el lobo se queda solo con la cabra se la come, si la cabra se queda sola con la col se la come.

El reto del granjero era cruzar él mismo y dejar sus compras a la otra orilla del río, dejando cada compra intacta. ¿Cómo lo hizo?

Answer (score 2):

En mi caso usando la parodia en el episodio "Gone Maggie Gone" de los   simpson, he modelado el problema creando las entidades rio, orilla y pasajero (Pensando que cruza en barco).

Luego ejecuto un test para ver si puedo hacer el cruce y lo imprime por pantalla si fracasa.

Es simple y no realizo todas las combinaciones para para probarlo. Quizás en la segunda iteración le haga un menu interactivo para jugar a cruzar el río.

Son libres de tocar el código y jugar, cualquier sugerencia se agradece.

Saludos.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
    * https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acertijo_del_lobo,_la_cabra_y_la_col
    */
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("** Homero, Maggie, Ayudante de Santa y Veneno **");

            Intento_01();
        }

        private static void Intento_01() {
            Pasajero homero = new Pasajero(TipoPasajero.Homero);
            Pasajero maggie = new Pasajero(TipoPasajero.Maggie);
            Pasajero perro = new Pasajero(TipoPasajero.AyudanteSanta);
            Pasajero veneno = new Pasajero(TipoPasajero.Veneno);

            Rio suquia = new Rio();

            suquia.getNorte().agregar(homero);
            suquia.getNorte().agregar(maggie);
            suquia.getNorte().agregar(perro);
            suquia.getNorte().agregar(veneno);

            Boolean exito = false;

            exito = suquia.Viajar(homero, maggie, Direccion.Sur);
            if (!exito) {
                System.out.println(suquia.toString());
            }

            exito = suquia.Viajar(homero, Direccion.Norte);
            if (!exito) {
                System.out.println(suquia.toString());
            }

            exito = suquia.Viajar(perro, homero, Direccion.Sur);
            if (!exito) {
                System.out.println(suquia.toString());
            }

            exito = suquia.Viajar(homero, Direccion.Norte);
            if (!exito) {
                System.out.println(suquia.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    enum Direccion {Norte, Sur}

    class Rio {
        private Orilla norte;
        private Orilla sur;

        public Rio() {
            norte = new Orilla(Direccion.Norte);
            sur = new Orilla(Direccion.Sur);
        }

        public Orilla getNorte() {
            return norte;
        }

        public Orilla getSur() {
            return sur;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return "\nRio {" +
                    "\nnorte=" + norte +
                    "\n, sur=" + sur +
                    "\n}";
        }

        public Boolean Viajar(Pasajero primer, Pasajero segundo, Direccion destino) {
            if (destino.equals(Direccion.Norte)) {
                sur.quitar(primer);
                sur.quitar(segundo);
                norte.agregar(primer);
                norte.agregar(segundo);
            } else {
                norte.quitar(primer);
                norte.quitar(segundo);
                sur.agregar(primer);
                sur.agregar(segundo);
            }

            boolean conflicto = HayConflicto(this.norte) || HayConflicto(this.sur);
            return !conflicto;
        }

        public Boolean Viajar(Pasajero primer, Direccion destino) {
            if (destino.equals(Direccion.Norte)) {
                sur.quitar(primer);
                norte.agregar(primer);
            } else {
                norte.quitar(primer);
                sur.agregar(primer);
            }

            boolean conflicto = HayConflicto(this.norte) || HayConflicto(this.sur);
            return !conflicto;
        }

        public Boolean HayConflicto(Orilla costa) {
            Boolean conflicto = true;

            if (costa.getPasajeros().stream()
                    .anyMatch(p -> p.getTipo().equals(TipoPasajero.Homero))) {
                return false;
            }

            for (Pasajero pas : costa.getPasajeros()) {
                conflicto = costa.getPasajeros().stream()
                        .anyMatch(p -> p.getTipo().seCome(pas.getTipo()));
            }

            return conflicto;
        }
    }

    class Orilla {
        private List<Pasajero> pasajeros;
        private Direccion ubicacion;

        public Orilla(Direccion ubicacion) {
            this.pasajeros = new ArrayList<Pasajero>();
            this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
        }

        public void agregar(Pasajero alguien) {
            if (getPasajeros().stream().anyMatch(p -> p.equals(alguien))) {
                System.out.println(alguien.toString() + " Ya estoy en la orilla " + this.ubicacion);
            } else {
                this.pasajeros.add(alguien);
            }
        }

        public void quitar(Pasajero alguien) {
            if (getPasajeros().stream().anyMatch(p -> p.equals(alguien))) {
                this.pasajeros.remove(alguien);
            } else {
                System.out.println(alguien.toString() + " NO estoy en la orilla " + this.ubicacion);
            }
        }

        public List<Pasajero> getPasajeros() {
            return pasajeros;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + pasajeros + '}';
        }
    }

    class Pasajero {
        private TipoPasajero tipo;

        public Pasajero(TipoPasajero tipo) {
            this.tipo = tipo;
        }

        public TipoPasajero getTipo() {
            return tipo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "\n\t" + tipo;
        }
    }

    enum TipoPasajero {
        Homero,
        Maggie,
        AyudanteSanta,
        Veneno;

        public boolean seCome(TipoPasajero otro) {
            if (this.equals(Maggie) && otro.equals(AyudanteSanta)) {
                return true;
            } else if (this.equals(AyudanteSanta) && otro.equals(Veneno)) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```